# How to a show the disc usage by directory in my home directory using the Terminal?

Tags: command-line, server, files, disk-usage

Could someone let me know which tool I should use? I'm trying to run this on an Ubuntu Server VM. So I believe I need a tool such as discus.

Comment: Have you already looked at `ncdu` ([http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu))?

Comment: @JeanPierreWenzel `ncdu` is a great answer - do you want to make an answer for it?

Answer (score 4):

*For use as **screen based terminal** program (curses/ncurses etc)*:

See `ncdu` - example output:

```
ncdu 1.10 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                    
--- /usr/share/icons -----------------------------------------------------------
  189.2MiB [##########] /oxygen                                                 
  169.3MiB [########  ] /hicolor
  130.2MiB [######    ] /HighContrast
  123.9MiB [######    ] /gnome
   74.0MiB [###       ] /nuvola
   57.9MiB [###       ] /Faience
   46.5MiB [##        ] /Breathe
   46.1MiB [##        ] /Faenza-Blue-Dark2
   43.2MiB [##        ] /AwOken
   40.1MiB [##        ] /elementary-xfce
   31.9MiB [#         ] /AwOkenDark
   26.4MiB [#         ] /elementary
 Total disk usage:   1.7GiB  Apparent size:   1.4GiB  Items: 308833
```

---

*For use on terminal in **line-by-line text mode***:

To show sorted sizes of subdirectories *and files* in the current directory:
*(For not showing files, see below)*

Run this in the directory containing the directories you want to measure,
$HOME in your example:

```
du -sch .* * | sort -hr | less
```

Or, just the same command in the more verbose long option form:

```
du --summarize --total --human-readable .* *  | sort --human-numeric-sort --reverse | less
```

This shows the

- `du` - **disk usage** inside the current directory,
- `-s` (`--summarize`) - showing a per item total value,
- `-c` (`--total`) - and a global total value as sum of all per item values,
- `-h` (`--human-readable`) - showing sizes as 6.8G, 4.0K, 5M etc, instead of byte counts,
- `.*` - listing files and directories named with dot as first character,
- `*` - and all other files and directories,
- `| sort -hr` - sort the result, handling the human readable file sizes, in reverse order,
- `| less` - and show the resulting list in a pager, largest on top.

**Note:** depending on the shell used, and it's options, using `.*` in a directory where no filenames starting with `.` exist may cause an error. In that case, the `.*` is redundant and can be left out (And that's what the error was trying to tell you)

Examples of output lines, in original sort order:

> ```
> 39G     total
> 7.7G    Downloads
> 6.8G    .local
> 3.4G    .mozilla
> 2.6G    .thunderbird
> 1.6G    dev
> 1.4G    .cache
> 490M    work
> 7.3M    AnInterestingPaper.pdf
> 60K     .bazaar
> 8.0K    .gitconfig
> 4.0K    .tigrc
> ```

---

For an exact answer of the question, the files need to be left out from the list.
It makes the list much more readable usualy, so it's worth to do; Just not when manually typing the command in a shell, as it get's  a bit long. So, for use in a script etc:

Use `find` to list only directories (do not use the common syntax `find . -foo` for the directory argument to prevent a `./` prefix on the file names in the result list):

```
find .* * -maxdepth 0 -type d -print0 | du --files0-from=- -sch | sort -hr | less
```

---

*For use with the **graphical desktop** (not the terminal as asked)*:
(Was not asked for, but adding a short hint on good GUI tools for the task for completenes.)

See `gdmap` and `filelight` (or `baobab`). Both provide very interesting diagrams, and to get the best intuitive view it is worth a try to combine `gdmap` with one of the other two.

Answer (score 0):

I use "du -c | sort -n | tail" to see which directories take up the most space. Not quite the same as what you are asking but I find it pretty useful.